# Requests library GET method redirects all responses with a location in the header or only responses with status code of 300s?

Tags: python, python-requests

I know that the `requests` library redirects automatically `GET` requests that have a `status code` of `300s`. But sometimes, programmers just send the `location` in the headers, but don't set the status for Redirection (`300s`).

So, I was wondering if `requests` redirects all responses with a `location` in the header, or if it redirects only responses with status code of `300s`? I tried to find this information in the documentation, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not explicitly stated in the documentation, but `requests` only follows ***redirects*** (automatically, or if instructed to do so via `allow_redirects=True`) - but not every response with a `Location` header necessarily is a redirect.

---

There are two main uses for the `Location` header:

- **Redirects**: Responses with status codes `3xx`
- Indicating the location of a **newly created resource** (status code `201`).

From
[RFC 7231, Section 7.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.2):

> The "Location" header field is used in some responses to refer to a
> specific resource in relation to the response.  **The type of
> relationship is defined by the combination of request method and
> status code semantics.**
>
> [...]
>
> For 201 (Created) responses, the Location value refers to the
> primary resource created by the request.  For 3xx (Redirection)
> responses, the Location value refers to the preferred target
> resource for automatically redirecting the request.

So only responses with a `Location` header *and* status code `3xx` are to be considered redirects. And the `requests` module checks for exactly that condition in [`Response.is_redirect()`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/dfdf371a0fea6d0fcd11a1c3f7e51cb3dd3528f9/requests/models.py#L625-L630):

```
@property
def is_redirect(self):
    """True if this Response is a well-formed HTTP redirect that could have
    been processed automatically (by :meth:`Session.resolve_redirects`).
    """
    return ('location' in self.headers and self.status_code in REDIRECT_STATI)
```

(checked by [`SessionRedirectMixin.resolve_redirects()`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/a0d9e0bc57c971823811de38e5733b4b85e575ae/requests/sessions.py#L99))